# Asymptotics of the optimal stopping time of a paying die game

Tags: stochastic-processes, stopping-times, dynamic-programming

This may be a question with really obvious analytical answers which I do not see.

You play a multistep game with a die with equal probability of generating any of $1,2,\cdots, n$ at each throw. At the end of each throw of the die, you may choose to stop the game and walk away with the same dollar amount as the number generated by the last roll of the die, or choose to pay \$1 to continue the game. The game can last indefinitely. What is the amount of money you expect to collect from this game? Is there an easy asymptotic formula of the expectation as $n\to\infty$?

Note that only at the end of roll $n$, the expected future income is $\frac{n+1}2$ should you decide to continue the game, since the $n+1$'st roll is the absolutely latest you have to stop. One can easily set up the recursion for the expectation of the game value at any step. But is there an asymptotic formula for it as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: Does the game cost 1 unit per throw?

Comment: @RobPratt: Thank you for spotting the missing information. I have edited the question. Please review.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a given $n$ we have to set a threshold $k$ that we will accept.  If we keep rolling the expected value of the roll we accept is $\frac 12(n+k+1)$.  On average it takes $\frac n{n-k}$ rolls to get one, so we pay that much.  The breakeven point comes when $$\frac 12(n+k+1)-\frac n{n-k}=k\\
(n-k)(n+k+1)-2n=2k(n-k)\\
n^2-k^2-k-n=2kn-2k^2\\
k^2-(2n+1)k+n^2-n=0\\
k=\frac12\left(2n+1\pm \sqrt{(2n+1)^2-4n^2+4n}\right)\\
k=n+\frac 12-\frac 12\sqrt{8n+1}\\
k \approx n-\sqrt {2n}+\frac 12$$
The expected value of the roll we accept is then $n-\frac {\sqrt {2n}}2+\frac 14$ and it takes $\frac {n}{\sqrt {2n}}$ tries to get one, so the payoff is about $n-\sqrt {2n}$

Comment: This is incorrect. After each roll, the optimal expected future income is greater than $\frac {n-1}2$ since that only account for the case when you stop at the next roll neglecting the possibility of continuing beyond the next step. The stopping threshold should be higher than $\frac{n-1}2$ and is a decreasing function of the time step.

Comment: @Hans:  you are right.  Here is a complete rewrite.

Comment: I do not understand your solution. By "threshold" do you mean the $k$ above which you stop and below which you pay to continue at the end of every roll? If so, it is not right since $k$ is a decreasing function of $t$ the chronological roll number rather than a constant. But maybe you mean $k$ to be an expectation of some sort. Could you please write out a detailed and rigorous derivation? Otherwise, it is hard to verify your solution.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant by threshold.  I do not believe $k$ is decreasing.  While it is true that as the game progresses I have spent more money buying rethrows, the ones I have already done are in the past.  That is the point of my sunk cost line.  My option is to accept the current roll or to roll again with the cost of the number of rolls *from here* to get a number above the threshold.

Comment: Your claim the threshold is a constant at least needs to be proved, even if it is correct --- actually I seriously doubt it is. I have explicitly presented the recursion formulation, with the sunk cost explicitly excluded in the formulation of function $u(t,i)$,  in my answer (please review it). I have demonstrated for a finite time horizon, the decision threhold is not a constant. If you claim otherwise for the infinite time horizon, you will *have* to *prove* it from the first principle. I think it is false.

Comment: Come to think of it, a constant threshold is definitely wrong. That would mean there is a positive probability the game would go on for arbitrarily long. That is false since it has to end before you pay up $\$n$.

Comment: The crucial difference between finite and infinite time is the continuation value of the game after any history is exactly the same as the value of the game from the beginning, which is not true for finite horizons. It is possible to show a constant threshold is optimal in the infinite case more rigorously using some results from optimal stopping and superharmonic functions, but the “sunk cost” intuition is right. You don’t necessarily need to stop after paying $n$ if the last roll was bad.

Comment: @JasonGaitonde: So you think this is the correct answer? Truth be told, I did think of the sunk cost argument which lead to the infinite horizon and constant threshold but rejected it for the appearance of the negative total payout. Maybe you two do have a sound reason. Why don't you write a full, detailed and rigorous proof as an answer?

Comment: @Hans:  after you have made a number of rolls you are in exactly the same position you were at the start but have paid some dollars for the rolls.  If you have a limited bank account, so you can only play a limited number of games, the strategy does not change.  If there is a limit, it is correct that the threshold should decrease.

Comment: I see your argument. Because of the infinite time horizon, you can formulate it as a Markov chain problem with the numbers rolled as time-independent states and a threshold. Then the left-hand side of your first equation is the expected payoff given threshold $k$. Should you not maximize that expression respect to $k$ which gives $k=n-\sqrt{\frac n2}$ rather than setting the expected payoff to some number such as $k$ as you have done?

Comment: The left side is the expected payoff given that we roll again.  Setting it equal to $k$ says if we roll $k$ we don't care whether we accept or roll again.  If we set the threshold to $n-\sqrt{\frac n2}$ we collect $ n-\frac 12\sqrt{\frac n2}$ and pay$ \frac n {\sqrt{\frac n2}}=\sqrt {2n}$ so we expect $n-\sqrt n\frac{3\sqrt 2}2$ which is worse.

Comment: The derivative approach works fine, too.  The derivative of the left side is $\frac k2-\frac n{(n-k)^2}$.  Setting that to $0$ gets $(n-k)^2=2n, k=n-\sqrt {2n}$

Comment: We each had a typo. I should have typed $k=n-\sqrt{2n}$. You should have typed the derivative of the left-hand side of your threshold equation to be $\frac12-\frac n{(n-k)^2}$. Would you mind I edit your answer to incorporate my interpretation of the problem as a Markov chain or would you rather I edit my own answer to reflect that?

Comment: I would let you put it in your answer.

Comment: I posed a variation on this problem.  Care to take a look? https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3300144/64809

Comment: I appreciate your formulation of the problem as your first equation. If instead of paying one dollar, we assume an interest rate $r$, your term $\frac1{1-\frac kn}$ will become $\frac r{1-\frac kn}$. But it is hard for me interpret this, because $\frac1{1-\frac kn}$ would be the mean time to get above the threshold $k$. But the effect of the interest rate should be multiplicative instead of additive. How would you have dealt with this variation?

Comment: By switching to the view that if you roll and do not hit the threshhold you are back where you started.  Imagine you play once per day and future money is discounted by a factor $r$ for each day.  If you pay tomorrow for tomorrow's roll, the expectation with threshhold $k, E(k)$ is $r (\frac 12(n+k+1) \cdot \frac {n-k+1}n + \frac {k-1}nE(k)-1)$  Solve for $E(k)$, differentiate, set to zero...

Comment: How would you solve for $E(k)$? Is it just $k$? I do not think you need $-1$ as the last term in the parenthesis. This seems deviates from your method of computing the expected stopping time, but rather using the dynamic programming method. I am taking the dynamic programming approach in my answer.

Comment: You set that whole expression equal to $E(k)$.  It is a linear equation which will give an expression in $n,k$.  The first term is what you get if you succeed on the next throw, the second is what you get if you fail on the next throw, and the $-1$ is the cost of the throw.

Comment: Are you saying $r\big(\frac12(n+k+1)\frac{n−k+1}n+\frac{k−1}nE(k)−1\big)=E(k)$? Then both $k$ and $E(k)$ need to be solved. How would you do that?

Comment: You solve for $E(k)$ as an expression in $n,k$.  $n$ is given.  Now you take $\frac {dE(k)}{dk}$ and set it to zero to find the maximum, which lets you find $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $v(t,i)$ be the optimal expected worth (the sum of current wealth and the expected future income) at the end of $t$'th roll having observed number $i$. It is worth emphasizing that $i$ is in this setting given and the subsequent decision is conditioned upon it. The rolls starting from $t=0$. We have
\begin{equation}
v(t,i)=\max\begin{cases} -t+i, \\
\mathbf E[v(t+1,j)|\mathcal F_t]-1
\end{cases}.
\end{equation}
Sett $u(t,i):=v(t,i)+t$ to exclude the sunk cost. Better yet, at each time $t$ it is more transparent to look at the expected future income $u(t,i)$ with a given $t$'th roll outcome of $i$.
\begin{equation}
u(t,i)=\max\begin{cases} i, \\
-1+\mathbf E[u(t+1,j)|\mathcal F_t]
\end{cases}.
\end{equation}
Let $x(t):=-1+E[u(t+1,j)|\mathcal F_t]$. It is important to note that $x(t)$ is a deterministic function dependent on $t$ only rather than a random variable. We stop and take $i$ if $i\ge x(t)$ and continue if $i<x(t)$. Therefore
\begin{align}
x(t-1)+1 &= \frac1n\Big(\sum_{i=\lfloor x\rfloor+1}^n i+\sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor x\rfloor}x(t)\Big)\\
&=\frac1n\Big(\frac12\big(n+\lfloor x(t)\rfloor+1)(n-\lfloor x(t)\rfloor\big)+\lfloor x(t)\rfloor x(t)\Big) \tag0
\end{align}
This is the same as @RossMillikan's equation of $k$ after setting $k:=x(t-1)=x(t)$. Dividing Equation $(0)$ by $n$,
$$\frac{x(t-1)+1}n =\frac12\Big[1-\Big(\frac{\lfloor x(t)\rfloor}n\Big)^2+\frac1n\Big(1-\frac{\lfloor x(t)\rfloor}n\Big)\Big]+\frac{\lfloor x(t)\rfloor}n\frac{x(t)}n. \tag1
$$
Note this is a difference equation for $x(t)$ as $x(t)$ has been shown to be deterministic rather than stochastic.

If the die generates a continuum amount of dollars with uniform distribution, with $\frac{x(t)}n\to y(t)$ as $n\to\infty$, the above iteration becomes
$$y(t-1)=\frac12\big(1+y(t)^2\big)\tag2.$$
Both recursions lead to the results that $x(t)$ and $y(t)$ respectively increase as $t$ decreases and converge as $t\to -\infty$.

---

The decision threshold of $i$ in the above formulation Equation $(1)$ decreases with $t$. $u(t=T,i)=i$ so $\mathbf E[u(t=T,j)|\mathcal F_{T-1}]=\frac{1+n}2$. The threshold at $t=T-1$ is $\frac{n-1}2$. Now for large $n$
$$\mathbf E[u(t=T-1,j)|\mathcal F_{T-2}]\approx\frac1n\Big[\Big(\frac{n-1}2\Big)^2+\frac12\Big(n-\frac{n-1}2\Big)\Big(n+\frac{1+n}2\Big)\Big]=\frac58n+\frac3{8n}.$$
So the threshold at $t=T-2$ is $\mathbf E[u(t=T-1,j)|\mathcal F_{T-2}]-1\approx \frac58n>\frac n2$ approximately the threshold at $t=T-1$ for large $n$.

So the decision threshold is decreasing at least for $t\in \{T-2,T-1,T\}$ and is not a constant.

Comment: This is not correct.  Your intuition that you can roll no more than $n+1$ times is not correct.  If you have managed to roll that many without meeting the threshold, which is very unlikely, you should still play the original strategy.  Yes, the overall is a loss, but the chance is very small, so the effect on the expected value is negligible.  For example, if $n=2,000,000$ the threshold from my answer is $1,998,000$ so you expect to win in $1000$ tries.  The chance of losing $2,000,000$ is $e^{-2000}$.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I am revisiting this question after a long hiatus. I do not understand your objection. Nowhere do I presume I can roll no more than $n+1$ times. Do you see anything wrong with my recursive setup for $u$ or $v$?

Comment: I didn't follow the logic, but you are still cutting off at $n+1$ rolls as in your question.  If I roll $1$ for $2n$ times in a row, I am guaranteed a loss but unless this has convinced me the die is unfair I should roll again.  If I stop I am $-2n$.  If I roll again I expect  $-1-2n+\frac {n+1}2=-\frac{3n+1}2$, which is better.  Yes, I am still behind, but I am behind less.

Comment: @RossMillikan: Sorry for coming back to this question after so long. I did agree that you were right at the time of our last conversation that $n$ should not be the upper bound of the number of rolls. But I had not time to revisit my own derivation. I have now deleted that condition of $n$ being the upper bound and checked my derivation. I think the latter is correct. Will you be so kind as to review my derivation?

Comment: If there is an upper limit to the number of rolls, the strategy will depend on how close you are to the end.  The question does not set an upper limit.  If there is none, the strategy will  not depend on how many rolls you have had.  The difference comes from the fact that if there is not limit, you will achieve the threshold with probability $1$.  If there is a limit, you may not achieve it and you should accept something lower.

Comment: @RossMillikan: I am trying to derive the result for the no time limit from the finite ending time sequence by letting $t\to -\infty$ in my formulation. I can derive the convergence for Equation (1). The recursion of the no-time limit case would just be $x$ independent of $t$ in Equation (1). That $x$ would be your threshold $k$. That would lead to an asymptotics similar to yours. Do you agree?

Comment: Yes, it should.